# Example of random variable with a unique moment sequence but mgf DNE in a neighborhood of 0

Tags: distributions, moments, moment-generating-function

Do you have an example of a random variable $X$ with a unique moment sequence but whose mgf does not exist in a neighborhood of 0?

In other words, I'm looking for a counterexample to the converse of the statement: if $M_X(t)$ exists in a neighborhood of 0, then the moments of $X$ uniquely determine its distribution.

Comment: *Every* random variable has a definite moment sequence.  By "unique moment sequence" do you mean this would be the only random variable with such moments?

Comment: Correct -- this would be the only random variable with such moments.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84219/whether-distributions-with-the-same-moments-are-identical  for non-unicity, but there the mgf do not exist in an open interval around zero

Answer (score 0):

You will not find such an example, this is explained at [Whether distributions with the same moments are identical](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84219/whether-distributions-with-the-same-moments-are-identical). For more information some other posts:

- [Undefined MGF but all moments finite?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/462908/undefined-mgf-but-all-moments-finite)
- [Existence of the moment generating function and variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32706/existence-of-the-moment-generating-function-and-variance)
- [Moment Generating Function for Lognormal Random Variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/389846/moment-generating-function-for-lognormal-random-variable)