# Existence of moment generating function

Tags: distributions, moment-generating-function, geometric-distribution

Give a example of discrete random variable for which mgf $M(t)=E\left(e^{tx}
\right)$ does not exist . I have tried with geometric(p) distribution when $(1−p)e^t≥1$
, the mgf does not converge. Is it correct approach ?

Comment: You are correct that there is no convergence for that $M(t)$ when  $t\ge -\log_e(1-p)$, but since that boundary  is positive you can extract all the moments from the behaviour $M(t)$ around $t=0$ and so it may not be a desired response.  I suspect that you are being asked either for something like the log-normal distribution (a continuous distribution) or for something where some of the moments do not exist.

Comment: You'll want a discrete distribution whose tail decreases more slowly than an exponential/geometric.

Comment: I have found a discrete of &f(x)= (6/π^2)*(1/k^2)& where k =1,2,3,... But still have confusion about the 'k' , will it be 'x' in place of 'k' in the range ?

Comment: Yes, your $K$ is the equivalent of $X$, so you would want to show that $E[e^{tK}]$ or $E[e^{tX}]$ did not converge at least for positive $t$

Comment: Welcome to CV.  There is a genuine question concerning what "does not exist" means, because it is *always* the case that $M$ exists as a *partial function:* $E[e^{tX}]$ is always defined for $t=0.$ (This is discussed in the posts at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/389846/, for instance.) Could you please clarify?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.